# Fadein & FadeOut Divs on Loop working fine - but not showing first DIV

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, fadein, fadeout

Right I have 3 divs that are fading in and out but there the first DIV is not working nor fading in at all, any idea why? I feel like my  code is all correct?

**jQuery/Javascript:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    function fade($ele) {
        $ele.fadeOut(1000).delay(4000).fadeIn(1000, function() {
            var $next = $(this).next('#HomeImage');
            fade($next.length > 0 ? $next : $(this).parent().children().first());
       });
    };  

    fade($('div#stretchParent > #HomeImage').first());
}); 
</script>
```

**HTML:**

```
<div id="stretchParent"><!-- Stretch -->
    <div id="HomeImage"></div>
    <div id="HomeImage"></div>
    <div id="HomeImage"></div>
</div><!-- Stretch End -->
```

I cannot seem to work it out?

Comment: *Sigh* ID's should be unique

Comment: if you change the ID to CLASS it will work just fine.

Comment: I tried out your code and all three divs fade: http://jsfiddle.net/e79LE/ (@Spokey - changing to classes makes the html valid, but doesn't actually make the JS work any differently that I can see - there's nothing there where having duplicated ids would confuse it...)

Comment: Thanks guys - found the issue, it was that I did not apply the css style: display:none - But thank you for spotting the problem with the id class's you are right there also!

Answer (score 0):

it is wrong to have more of the same id on the page, use class instead id.

```
<div id="stretchParent">
    <div class="HomeImage"></div>
    <div class="HomeImage"></div>
    <div class="HomeImage"></div>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
fade($('div#stretchParent > .HomeImage').first());
```

Comment: That's true, but I don't think it actually causes a problem with the JS code shown in the question: http://jsfiddle.net/e79LE/

Comment: Thanks guys - found the issue, it was that I did not apply the css style: display:none - But thank you for spotting the problem with the id class's you are right there also!